# Store result of exec sql in a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a piece of code that runs fine but I would like to store the output of the Exec(@sql) into a temporary table.

```
Declare @Date date
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @Date= DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
Set @sql='SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
           ''SQLNCLI'',
           ''Server=Servername;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
           ''select * from servername.dbo where 
                  cast( (substring(cast(convert(date,createtsdt) as char (10)),1,4) + substring(cast(convert(date,createtsdt) as char (10)),6,2) 
                   +substring(cast(convert(date,createtsdt) as char (10)),9,2) ) as varchar(8) ) >=' + 
                    cast( (substring(cast(convert(date,@Date) as char (10)),1,4) + substring(cast(convert(date,@Date) as char (10)),6,2) 
                   +substring(cast(convert(date,@Date) as char (10)),9,2) ) as varchar(8) ) + ''')'

Exec @sql1
```

How I can store the output that exec @sql1 generates into a temp table

Comment: Use insert into YourTempTable select ....

Comment: Just a side note: why are you doing `convert(date,@Date)` when `@Date` is already declared as type `date`...

Answer (score 2):

You can create the table and use `insert . . . exec`.

Something like:

```
create table #t as (
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key
    createtsdt date
);

insert into #t (createtsdt)
    exec(@sql1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding an `INSERT INTO` like:

```
Set @sql= N'INSERT INTO #TEMP (Col1, ...) SELECT Col1, ... 
FROM OPENROWSET(....
```

Comment: that #temp table inside @sql would not be accessible from outside.